# How to select row information in dataframe over ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, selection

I'm new in python. I have a large dataframe as like that :

```
    ID  x   y
0   1   x1  y1
1   0   x2  y2
2   0   x3  y3
3   2   x4  y4
4   1   x5  y5
5   2   x6  y6
```

I would like to take couples of (x;y) between the IDs 1 and 2, in a dataframe like this :

```
    coordinates
0   (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)
1   (x5,y5), (x6,y6)
```

I already tried a double for iteration but it is to long to compute. How can I get this thing?

Comment: What's the logic here? Why does `0` in your output contain coords from ID's `1`, `0` and `2`?

Comment: I'd like to constitute some trajectories based on an ID : 1 is the beggining, 2 is the end and 0 is between those two ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is create groups by each `1` starting values and aggregate custom lambda function for tuples:

```
df['new'] = (df['ID'] == 1).cumsum()
print (df)
   ID   x   y  new
0   1  x1  y1    1
1   0  x2  y2    1
2   0  x3  y3    1
3   2  x4  y4    1
4   1  x5  y5    2
5   2  x6  y6    2

df1 = (df.groupby('new')['x','y']
         .apply(lambda x: list(map(tuple, x.values.tolist())))
         .reset_index(name='coordinates'))
print (df1)
   new                               coordinates
0    1  [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]
1    2                      [(x5, y5), (x6, y6)]
```

Similar solution with no new column:

```
df1 = (df.groupby((df['ID'].rename('new') == 1).cumsum())['x','y']
         .apply(lambda x: list(map(tuple, x.values.tolist())))
         .reset_index(name='coordinates'))
print (df1)
   new                               coordinates
0    1  [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]
1    2                      [(x5, y5), (x6, y6)]
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   ID   x   y
0   1  x1  y1
1   0  x2  y2
2   0  x3  y3
3   2  x4  y4
4   0  x7  y7
4   0  x8  y8
4   1  x5  y5
5   2  x6  y6

g = df['ID'].eq(1).cumsum()
s = df['ID'].shift().eq(2).cumsum()

df = df[s.groupby(g).transform('min').eq(s)]
print (df)
   ID   x   y
0   1  x1  y1
1   0  x2  y2
2   0  x3  y3
3   2  x4  y4
4   1  x5  y5
5   2  x6  y6

df1 = (df.groupby((df['ID'].rename('new') == 1).cumsum())['x','y']
         .apply(lambda x: list(map(tuple, x.values.tolist())))
         .reset_index(name='coordinates'))
print (df1)
   new                               coordinates
0    1  [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]
1    2                      [(x5, y5), (x6, y6)]
```

Comment: Solution will create groups even if ending "2" value is not present. For example if ID=[1,0,1,2,1,2] three groups will be created instead of only 2 if directly follow requirement. Is it possible to group only if complete boundary (1,2) is in the data?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! What if there is some 0 between 2 and 1? I prefer to ask in case of there are some..

Comment: @jezrael Sorry I'm kind of new here, I thought we could accept two answers... As like that, can you help me?

Comment: @nicolax9777 - Sure, I help you.

Comment: @nicolax9777 - If there are `0` rows between `2` and `1`, then should be omit?

Comment: @jezrael Yes should be omit, but conserved because I have to count them in order to quantify how many failed data I have ! Thank you a lot

Comment: @jezrael THANKS A LOT ! Amazing, it just took 5 sec to run

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) tuple across axis 1, and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your "groups" using [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with [`eq(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and use `list` [aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
(df[['x', 'y']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
 .groupby(df['ID'].eq(1).cumsum()).agg(list))
```

[out]

```
ID
1    [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]
2                        [(x5, y5), (x6, y6)]
dtype: object
```

---

or if expected output is a comma-separated string of coords, you could `apply` `join` function:

```
(df[['x', 'y']].apply(tuple, axis=1).astype(str)
 .groupby(df['ID'].eq(1).cumsum()).apply(', '.join))
```

[out]

```
ID
1    ('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2'), ('x3', 'y3'), ('x4', 'y4')
2                                ('x5', 'y5'), ('x6', 'y6')
dtype: object
```